# Jquery associate two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would realy appreciate any help with this. Is there any way to simplify this code? I would like to pair elements of both arrays with the same index to perform specific functions.

```
  var insects = ['#redhairy', '#bollworm', '#stalk', '#stem', '#chuija', '#diamond', '#pyrilla'];
var plants = ['.groundnut', '.cotton', '.maize', '.rice', '.wheat', '.mustard', '.sugarcane'];


$(insects[0]).hover(function(){
  $(plants[0]).toggleClass('active');
});

$(insects[1]).hover(function(){
  $(plants[1]).toggleClass('active');
});

$(insects[2]).hover(function(){
  $(plants[2]).toggleClass('active');
});

$(insects[3]).hover(function(){
  $(plants[3]).toggleClass('active');
});

$(insects[4]).hover(function(){
  $(plants[4]).toggleClass('active');
});

$(insects[5]).hover(function(){
  $(plants[5]).toggleClass('active');
});

$(insects[6]).hover(function(){
  $(plants[6]).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Your HTML tags are not well balanced. Consistent indentation is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the HTML you could add a `data` attribute to the elements which receive the hover event which is the selector for the element that is to have the class toggled. This way you can group them with a common class and only use one selector, like this:

```js
$('.item').hover(function() {
  $($(this).data('target')).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { 
  color: #C00; 
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="redhairy" class="item" data-target=".groundnut">Red hariy</div>
<div id="bollworm" class="item" data-target=".cotton">Bollworm</div>

<div class="groundnut">Groundnut</div>
<div class="cotton">Cotton</div>
```

Alternatively, if you can't amend the HTML you could loop through the array and put a event handler on each element individually, using the index of the loop to get each item from the array:

```js
var insects = ['#redhairy', '#bollworm', '#stalk', '#stem', '#chuija', '#diamond', '#pyrilla'];
var plants = ['.groundnut', '.cotton', '.maize', '.rice', '.wheat', '.mustard', '.sugarcane'];

insects.forEach(function(insect, i) {
  $(insect).hover(function() {
    $(plants[i]).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active { 
  color: #C00; 
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="redhairy" class="item">Red hariy</div>
<div id="bollworm" class="item">Bollworm</div>

<div class="groundnut">Groundnut</div>
<div class="cotton">Cotton</div>
```

Note that the first method, which amends the HTML, is by *far* the better option here. Also note that `forEach()` relies on browser support of ES2015. If you need to support older browsers (such as IE) you'll need to use a polyFill, or a `for()` loop instead.

Comment: Hi Rory, I used first method. Works perfectly! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a matrix (2D Array) with per line the insect and its plant. this build is easy with map().

```js
var insects = ['#redhairy', '#bollworm', '#stalk', '#stem', '#chuija', '#diamond', '#pyrilla'];
var plants = ['.groundnut', '.cotton', '.maize', '.rice', '.wheat', '.mustard', '.sugarcane'];
var pairs = insects.map((x,i) => [x, plants[i]]);
console.log(pairs);
```